# Error while burning bootloader onto ATMega-8A using Arduino Mega 2560: avrdude: invalid byte value

Tags: arduino-mega, isp, atmega

So, I'm trying to burn the bootloader onto an ATMega 8A with an Arduino Mega 2560 as ISP.
I made the necessary connections, and got this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega8 -cstk500v1 -P\\.\COM3 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3f:m -Uhfuse:w:0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}:m -Ulfuse:w:0b{bootloader.bod_bits}{bootloader.sut_cksel_bits}:m 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM3
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA8
         Chip Erase delay              : 10000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom         4    20   128    0 no        512    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         33    10    64    0 yes      8192   64    128  4500  4500 0xff 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [80]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [02] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [98]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [84]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [85]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [86]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [87]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [89]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: B [42] p [70] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [02] . [ff] . [00] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] @ [40] . [02] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [c2] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [1e] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [01] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [93] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [02] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [07] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################################## | 100% 0.06s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9307
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [01] . [fc] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [01] . [fd] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [01] . [fe] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [01] . [ff] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [ac] . [80] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: B [42] p [70] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [02] . [ff] . [00] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] @ [40] . [02] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [c2] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: reading input file "0x3f"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | avrdude: Send: V [56] X [58] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x3f:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x3f:
avrdude: input file 0x3f contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | avrdude: Send: V [56] X [58] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified
avrdude: reading input file "0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}"
avrdude: invalid byte value (0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}) specified for immediate mode
avrdude: read from file '0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}' failed
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

These are my fuse bits:

```
# General
8.name=ATmega8 (8MHz Internal Clock on breadboard)
8.upload.tool=avrdude
8.upload.maximum_data_size=1024
8.bootloader.tool=avrdude
8.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3f
8.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0f
8.bootloader.low_fuses=0b{bootloader.bod_bits}{bootloader.sut_cksel_bits}
8.bootloader.high_fuses=0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}
8.build.core=MCUdude_corefiles
8.build.variant=standard
8.build.board=AVR_ATmega8
8.build.mcu=atmega8
8.build.bootloader_led=B5

# Upload port select
8.menu.bootloader.uart0=Yes (UART0)
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.upload.maximum_size=7680
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.upload.protocol=arduino
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.upload.port=UART0
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.build.export_merged_output=true
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.bootloader.bootrst_bit=0
8.menu.bootloader.uart0.bootloader.file=optiboot_flash/bootloaders/{build.mcu}/{build.f_cpu}/optiboot_flash_{build.mcu}_{upload.port}_{upload.speed}_{build.f_cpu}_{build.bootloader_led}.hex

8.menu.bootloader.no_bootloader=No bootloader
8.menu.bootloader.no_bootloader.upload.maximum_size=8192
8.menu.bootloader.no_bootloader.build.export_merged_output=false
8.menu.bootloader.no_bootloader.bootloader.bootrst_bit=1
8.menu.bootloader.no_bootloader.bootloader.file=empty/empty.hex

# EEPROM
8.menu.eeprom.keep=EEPROM retained
8.menu.eeprom.keep.bootloader.eesave_bit=0
8.menu.eeprom.erase=EEPROM not retained
8.menu.eeprom.erase.bootloader.eesave_bit=1

# Brown out detection - This is the first part of the low fuse bit concatenation
8.menu.BOD.2v7=BOD 2.7V
8.menu.BOD.2v7.bootloader.bod_bits=10
8.menu.BOD.4v0=BOD 4.0V
8.menu.BOD.4v0.bootloader.bod_bits=00
8.menu.BOD.disabled=BOD disabled
8.menu.BOD.disabled.bootloader.bod_bits=11

# Compiler link time optimization
8.menu.LTO.Os=LTO disabled
8.menu.LTO.Os.compiler.c.extra_flags=
8.menu.LTO.Os.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=
8.menu.LTO.Os.compiler.cpp.extra_flags=
8.menu.LTO.Os.ltoarcmd=avr-ar

8.menu.LTO.Os_flto=LTO enabled
8.menu.LTO.Os_flto.compiler.c.extra_flags=-Wextra -flto -g
8.menu.LTO.Os_flto.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=-w -flto -g
8.menu.LTO.Os_flto.compiler.cpp.extra_flags=-Wextra -flto -g
8.menu.LTO.Os_flto.ltoarcmd=avr-gcc-ar

8.menu.clock.8MHz_internal=8 MHz internal
8.menu.clock.8MHz_internal.upload.speed=38400
8.menu.clock.8MHz_internal.bootloader.sut_cksel_bits=100100
8.menu.clock.8MHz_internal.bootloader.ckopt_bit=1
8.menu.clock.8MHz_internal.build.f_cpu=8000000L
```

Should I try deleting unnescessary stuff from the fuse bits?

I tried checking the fuse bits, but they're pretty much alien to me. Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance
Me

Edit: I am using Arduino IDE v1.0.5 and have selected "Arduino as ISP" in the programmer.

Comment: The existence of unreplaced placeholders (e.g. `{bootloader.bod_bits}`) is significant in the output. Include your IDE version number and the name and version number of the board package you're using for ATMega8A support, and what you have selected in the menus, etc.  Maybe someone can replicate the error even without an ATMega8 on hand.

Comment: Arduino 1.0.5, "Arduino as ISP" programmer, and custom boards.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.0.5 is from 2013 and a lot has changed in the IDE since then, particularly between the 1.0.x versions and the 1.5.x versions. Most people wind up with 1.0.5 because it's in the Ubuntu's (and other Linux distribution's) package repo(s).

Anyway, it's likely that this old version doesn't define some of the things your board definition is referencing. E.g. you're referring to names that exist in the 1.8.x platform.txt file that don't exist in the 1.0.5 IDE. When the IDE fails to replace a key placeholder, it leaves it like you're seeing in your avrdude commandline: `-Uhfuse:w:0b110{bootloader.ckopt_bit}{bootloader.eesave_bit}10{bootloader.bootrst_bit}:m -Ulfuse:w:0b{bootloader.bod_bits}{bootloader.sut_cksel_bits}:m`   You should not be seeing these `{blah}` references in your command-lines when compiling or uploading.

Actually, 1.0.5 predates the handling of [`.menu.` style properties](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.23/platform-specification/#custom-board-options). E.g. They used to have entire separate boards.txt entries for the [ATMega328P based nano](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.0.5/hardware/arduino/boards.txt#L65) and the [ATMega168 based nano](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.0.5/hardware/arduino/boards.txt#L86) and these are now handled by a single board with a [`.menu.cpu.` section](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.5/boards.txt#L208-L253) for the selection of the MCU used. So under 1.0.5 none of your `.menu.` properties are failing to be replaced by the IDE.

So, I would start by getting rid of the old IDE and instead installing the latest [from the official site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/software) and seeing if that improves things.

That said, if you want to use the ATMega8A with Arduino it would probably be better to use [MCUdude MiniCore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore) rather than modifying the regular boards.txt file. You'll need a new IDE in order to use that anyway.